# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpRequestMessage' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm adapting a project recently started in .NET Standard to use Azure Functions. I have an HTTP trigger that I am posting directly to from a form. There are only 2 fields: a number input, and a file upload.

When using the function without referencing any other libraries, I cannot use ReadAsFormDataAsync on the HttpRequestMessage. I receive a:

```
System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter is 
available to read an object of type 'FormDataCollection' from content with 
media type 'multipart/form-data'.
```

I can use ReadAsMultipartAsync and manage to get the post values.

When I reference a .NET Standard library though, I can't even enter the function as it gets completely rejected:

```
System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter is 
available to read an object of type 'HttpRequestMessage' from content with 
media type 'multipart/form-data'
```

I tried creating a brand new skeleton .NET Standard library and referencing that and same thing.

As an additional reference I found [this post](http://intranoggin.com/Blog/March-2017/Azure-Functions-System-Net-Http%E2%80%93A-Very-Painful-Er.aspx), but I don't seem to be having the same issue.

Was going to file an issue but decided to try here first. Any ideas?

EDIT: This also happens when the enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know,  the "ReadAsFormDataAsync" method only accepts "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" type of contents. It doesn't support get the 'multipart/form-data' type of contents.

So if you want to send multiple part of contests, you need use "ReadAsMultipartAsync" method.

More details about how to use "ReadAsMultipartAsync" method in azure function, you could refer to this codes:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
     string result = "- -";
            if (req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).Wait();
                foreach (HttpContent ctnt in provider.Contents)
                {
                    //now read individual part into STREAM
                     var stream = ctnt.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                     return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Stream Length " + stream.Result.Length);

                        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            //do something with the stream
                        }

                }
            }
            if (req.Content.IsFormData())
            {
                NameValueCollection col = req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $" {col[0]}");
            }

            // dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();

            // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Doesn't get anything " + result);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I should have noted in the original post that this happens with that enctype as well. I will edit to add that.

Comment: In my side, I could get the application/x-www-form-urlencoded request. If possible please post the whole azure function http trigger codes, you used now.

Comment: [FunctionName("TestPost")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    string name = data?.name;

    
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}

The function doesn't get entered because it fails with: Exception binding parameter 'req' and another error: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpRequestMessage' from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Comment: According to your codes, you don't change codes to get the 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' value. I suggest you could try my codes and test again.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I'm saying. I can't even get into the function. When using either form type, the function won't even form the request object. It just rejects it with the stated errors. Getting the post values from the request object is the easy part

Comment: Could you please edit the question about how you send the request to the azure function and the total codes your azure function you have used now(with which libraries you have import)? According to your description, we couldn't repro the issue you have now.

Comment: This is exactly the code I needed where a File Upload control I was using had file data being sent as multipart data and the sample code given didn't particularly clue me into how the data was being sent or how to process it further. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the content type as JSON on your HTTP request headers?

```
Content-Type=application/json
```