# Azure function send email with attachment

Tags: azure-functions, postman

I wrote an Azure function for sending an email, here is the definition

```
    [FunctionName("SendEmail")]
    public static async Task<ApiResult> SendEmailAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    SendEmailDataInput input,
    [ServiceBus("sb", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)] 
    IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage> collector, ILogger log)
    {
        (...)
    }
```

I am testing the function with Postman, and it works if I put in the part "raw data" a Json structure that corresponds with the class SendEmailDataInput. But I would like to also add an attachment to the email. So how can I modify the function definition, and how can I test it in Postman, in order to send a Json containing the email data + a file?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: [No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpRequestMessage' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949830/no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-to-read-an-object-of-type-httprequestmessage/45972564)

The key was to take the request as HttpRequestMessage (instead of my class SendEmailDataInput), in this way I can take the form data in different formats.